# untar creates read-only folder in mounted volume on xenial in Docker

Tags: 18.04, mount, docker, tar

I cannot untar an archive as root on xenial due to `Cannot mkdir: Permission denied`.

**Environment**

- Ubuntu 18.04 Docker container
- Host OS: macOS but this is likely irrelevant, I can't test on other host OS
- Mounting volume from host system to `/tmp/folder`
- Docker cmd: ``` docker run -ti --rm -v ``pwd``:/tmp/nodemcu-firmware ubuntu:18.04 /bin/bash ```

**Steps to reproduce**

- `cd /tmp/nodemcu-firmware`
- `mkdir cache && cd cache`
- `apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget xz-utils`
- `wget https://github.com/jmattsson/esp-toolchains/releases/download/linux-x86_64-20181106.0/toolchain-esp32-linux-x86_64-20181106.0.tar.xz`
- `tar -xJf toolchain-esp32-linux-x86_64-20181106.0.tar.xz`

Unpacking fails because `tar` creates a new folder `esp32-linux-x86_64-20181106.0` from the archive but it's read-only: `dr-x------`. Hence, unpacking all subsequent (child) artifacts fails.

Unpacking the same tarball *outside* this mounted Docker volume works just fine. Whose fault is this? Docker's, Ubuntu's or mine?

**Update 2019-07-31**

The root cause are odd permissions in the tarball.

```
$ tar -tvf toolchain-esp32-linux-x86_64-20181106.0.tar.xz|grep dr-
dr-xr-xr-x johny/johny       0 2018-11-06 02:07 esp32-linux-x86_64-20181106.0/
```

I don't know how to solve the problem but the author agreed to create a new tarball with updated permissions.

Comment: What's your `umask`? How is `/tmp/nodemcu-firmware` mounted? Does `tar -tJf toolchain-esp32-linux-x86_64-20181106.0.tar.xz` show the directory permission as wrong? Why `tar -xJF`? Isn't `tar -xJf` better? `-F` has to do with multivolume restores, and how to announce "End-of-Volume, Supply next Volume", while `-f` just says "next parameter is the filename".

Comment: `umask` is 0022. `-F` vs `-f` was a typo here, sorry. I'm actually dissecting someone else's Makefile to see why it doesn't run in my environment: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/dev-esp32/Makefile#L25. Running `tar --no-same-permissions -xJf ...` results in different permissions of the upacked root folder `dr-xr-xr-x` but the rest still fails (of course).

Comment: Is there a way change permissions of each extracted folder _on-the-fly_ i.e. while unpacking?

Comment: Yes, with `iwatch`. Or use my `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld` to explore your directory.

Comment: You are encouraged to Edit your question to fix typos or add information. Information posted in comments won't  be read later.